# Query to get records from quarter before current quarter in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get records from quarter before current quarter in MySQL. But not able to figure out how the query will be constructed.

My MySQL table:

[image]

Here's my query to get records of current quarter (Jan 2020 to March 2020):

```
SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE QUARTER(`customer_date`) = QUARTER(CURRENT_DATE) 
AND YEAR(`customer_date`) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) 
ORDER BY `customer_date` DESC
```

But when I am using following query to get records from quarter before current quarter i.e. records from `Oct 2019 to Dec 2019`, the query doesn't yield me correct result. Actually it fetches records of every quarter (Oct to Dec) of all previous years in the table:

```
SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE QUARTER(`customer_date`) = QUARTER(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 QUARTER) 
ORDER BY `customer_date` DESC
```

I can't use `YEAR` in above query. If I use the year then query will fail when it will be run in the future e.g. in the quarter of Apr 2020 to Jun 2020.

How can this query be modified to get required result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this will do:

```
select
    *
from
    customers
where
    quarter(`customer_date`) = quarter(current_date - interval 1 quarter)
    and year(customer_date) =
    (case
        when quarter(curdate()) > 1 then year(current_date)
        else year(current_date)-1
    end)
order by
    `customer_date` desc
```

> [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6006c045baf19e19bcfe9834693ca31a)

Comment: Wonderful! It really worked like a charm. Thanks. Can you please explain the `CASE` part?

Comment: In the case we are checking the current quarter. If current quarter is 2,3 or 4 then no need to change year, but if current quarter is 1 then previous quarter will be 4th quarter of the previous year. So that logic is in the CASE.